# How to reconfigure Apache Ignite instances without losing the cache data

Tags: ignite

I would like to change the `IgniteConfiguration` while the system is running.

I'm currently doing that by stopping the node, then starting it again with the new configuration object:

```
// close the previous instance
_ignite.close();
// start a new one with the changed configuration
_ignite = Ignition.start(config);
```

This causes the cache to lose all data unless I enable disk persistence.

Is there any other way to do this without losing the node's caches data?

Comment: I believe it somewhat depends on what you are trying to change. How many nodes do you have? Are there backups configured? Do you have any concerns about persistence?

Comment: It may be a single node or a cluster of several nodes. What can change is the port, number of backups, TLS settings for the cluster or the discovery SPI.

Comment: About concerns: we can't lose any data at all. Persistence is not desired if possible, I only added persistence because of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change Communication or Discovery SPIs configurations dynamically without the node restart.

You can configure backups for the caches, as described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuring-backups), to avoid data loss after the node restart in the in-memory multi-node cluster.

In case you would like to modify a cache configuration, such as backups count, it will require destroying of the existing cache and creating a new one with an updated configuration. You can find more details regarding that [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/basic-cache-operations#destroying-caches) and [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/basic-cache-operations#creating-caches-dynamically).